# Displaying Date in Javascript table that is returned into a list

Tags: javascript

I have the following code, in which a table is built in JavaScript and passed to the HTML using an `ID`.

```
html += "<tbody>"
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

               html += "<tr><td>" + list[i].GroupId + "</td>";
               html += "<td>" + list[i].GroupType + "</td>";
               html += "<td>" + list[i].GroupName + "</td>";
               html += "<td>" + list[i].Updated + "</td>";
               html += "<td>" + list[i].MemberCount + "</td>";
           }

html += "</tbody>"
```

My problem is that `list[i].Updated` returns a date and it looks like the following `/Date(1448996589783)/`. How can I convert this so it displays as the proper date on the page?

Comment: `new Date(timestamp)`

Comment: More likely `new Date(list[i].Updated.replace(/[^0-9]/g,""))`

Comment: don't forget to close your `<tr>` tag

Comment: @DanielKobe Either that or remove all the `</td>`s for consistency - none of them are technically required :)

Comment: @JamesThorpe Id leave them in case you want to style by `td` later

Comment: @DanielKobe I was referring to the closing tags - they can be omitted in many cases, including here

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I tried this html += "<td>" + new Date (list[i].Updated.replace(/[^0-9]/g,"")) + "</td>"; but it returns 'Invalid Date'. I need the <td> tags, its the way my table needs to be set up. The date that is brought back from the database is 12/1/2015 7:03:09 PM, and this is the one I am looking to display.

Comment: @JamesThorpe oh I see, learn something new every day. Or you can just use `Jade` and never close a tag again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help people, but after messing around and a lot of google searching I managed to figure this out. I created another function as shown below in the JavaScript file:

```
function parseJsonDate(jsonDateString)
            {
                 return new Date(parseInt(jsonDateString.substr(6))).toLocaleString();
            }
```

and updated my list[] to this:

```
html += "<td>" + parseJsonDate(list[i].Updated) + "</td>";
```

and when run it displays exactly what I wanted: 12/1/2015 7:03:09 PM